# jQuery doWhen setup

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Trying to figure out how to get doWhen working.
My index.html:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.dowhen.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/foo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/underscorejs/1.5.2/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

In my foo.js:

```
function invoker (NAME, METHOD) {
  return function(target /* args ... */) {
    if (!existy(target)) fail("Must provide a target"); var targetMethod = target[NAME];
    var args = _.rest(arguments);
    return doWhen((existy(targetMethod) && METHOD === targetMethod),
                    function() { return targetMethod.apply(target, args);
    });
};
};
```

I have a test that ultimately call invoker(), and I'm getting:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: doWhen is not defined
```

My ordering of scripts seems to be ok, so I do not know why I'm getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

There is **no** such function as `doWhen`

It is [a jQuery plugin](https://github.com/epickerel/dowhen), try doing this:

```
$.doWhen(...)
```

Comment: Now is not recognizing "$"

Comment: Are you using `noConflict`? Try using `jQuery` instead.

Comment: Using "jQuery" same problem as with "$", I'll see how to use noConflict

Comment: Going to use jquery when.do instead